# Modelling random walks for double spending based on hashrate

Tags: doublespend, hashpower, math

I'm reading [Analysis of hashrate-based double-spending](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2009.pdf) where the following assumptions are made (on page 5):

- The total hashrate of the honest network and the attacker is constant, say `H`. Let the honest network have `pH` hashrate while the attacker has `qH` hashrate, `p` + `q` = 1.
- Mining difficulty is constant, and with hashrate `H` the average time to mine a block is `T_0`.

The author writes that if the honest network and attacker start mining blocks at the same time then the probability that the former (resp. latter) mines a block first is `p` (resp. `q`).
Now, while it is intuitive to grasp why this should be true, I am unable to prove so.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a formal "proof" available as this is implied by basic logic.

Assuming a block is found (aka mined) in future and there are only two mining subgroups "Honest" and "Attacker". If they have equal hashpower (p=0.5, q=0.5) then they are searching the solution space at the same rate and each has a 50 percent chance of finding this next block. If Honest has twice the hashpower of Attacker (p=2/3, q=1/3) then Honest is searching the solution space at twice the rate of Attacker and hence has twice the probability of finding the next block. Similarly with p=0.8, q=0.2 Honest is searching the solution space at 4 times the rate of Attacker and has 4 times the probability of finding the next block.